# Simple HTML Dom: How to remove span element?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I want to remove a span Element with Simple HTML Dom

```
<tr style="background-color:#ccffcc;">
<td style="text-align:center;"> 1.</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">Tante</td>
<td style="text-align:center;"><span style="visibility:hidden;">0</span>70:13<span style="visibility:hidden;">0</span></td>
</tr>
```

How can I remove the span?

```
// initialize empty array to store the data array from each row
$theData = array();

// loop over rows
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {

    // initialize array to store the cell data from each row
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($row->find('td') as $cell) {

        foreach($cell->find('span') as $e)
    {
        $e->outertext = '';
    }

        // push the cell's text to the array
        $rowData[] = $cell->plaintext;
    }

    // push the row's data array to the 'big' array
    $theData[] = $rowData;
}
```

The Code works fine but do not remove the span.

Comment: try using .remove() if you want to complete remove the element or if you want to remove only the content use .empty()

Comment: i think css will also work `td span{ display:none}`

Comment: I change  $e->outertext = ''; to  $e->innertext = ''; And it works fine

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm see this link to more information innertext outertext